# Where does php store uploaded files and for how long? FILES array says in /tmp but I do not see them

Tags: php, image-uploading

I'm writing a portion of a php application, and when all of the forms have been filled out (2 pages of forms), the user has the option to 'preview' their post before submitting it to the db.  Using sessions to store the text information is easy enough, and when I get to the preview page, I can simply pull the text data from session.  The problem is, they can also upload an image with their post.  I know that I can move_uploaded_file the image to a temp location, display it, and then delete it once the user posts/decides not to post.  But I'm wondering if I can just pull the image from this /tmp location and display it just for the preview page without having to move_uploaded_file.  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The uploaded data is removed from the /tmp location when the script finishes. If you do not move it to another location, it will be gone forever. It works like this:

- HTTP request comes in with uploaded file data
- PHP moves the data into a tmp file
- PHP starts your script, puts the name of the tmp file into the `$_FILES` array
- when your script is finished, PHP removes the tmp file, if it's still present

Comment: I don't know. A combination of the manual, experience and teh intarwebs I guess.